# I am trying to see my clock on my JFrame, but it keeps writing over top itself

Tags: java

I am working on a clock in a JFrame but it keeps on overwriting itself and causing a blur on the screen.

```
//starting new Thread which will update time 
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            updateTime();
        } catch (Exception ie) {}
    }
}).start();
}
public void updateTime() {
    try {
        while (true) { // geting Time in desire format 
            time.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a").format(new java.util.Date())); 
            // Thread sleeping for 1 sec 
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in Thread Sleep : " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a frame.add(time); to my program but it just keeps on writing over top itself I wish I could post my code but stack overflow wont let me

Comment: I'm going to assume 'time' is a JLabel component. Simply clear the JLabel text before you write the time within it:   jLabel1.setText("");  Your code is really required here to see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: there is my code for the time, I tried to time.setText(" "); to nothing but it still kept overwriting the time...WHere do I put the setText( " " ); at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is a working example of how to update a JLabel on JFrame. I used your code and added a few things on top of it. Looks like you have some different problem since my JLabel is being updated every second. Please copy the code and run it. I hope this will help you find the problem.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class teset {

private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
private static JLabel time = new JLabel();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame.add(time);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                updateTime();
            } catch (Exception ie) {
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void updateTime() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            time.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a").format(new java.util.Date()));
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in Thread Sleep : " + e);
    }
}
```

}